# How to read Qr Code through browser and decode its data

Tags: jquery

I need to scan a QRCODE from browser , then decoded and get its Data .

Could anybody please let me know if there is any such possibilty ??

I have seeen Jquery Scanner Detection avialable for this .

Is there any example of scanning a QR code in browser and get its data ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Look @ this http://webqr.com/index.html are you looking something like this? Or Something like in the below plugin http://www.jqueryrain.com/2013/10/best-jquery-webcam-plugin-example/

Comment: I have seen this http://www.jqueryrain.com/?gZnCZrwy , this is just opening the camera , but not decoding the QRcode  .

Comment: I mean to say that in the source code , the call back method is not working . $('#qrcodebox').WebcamQRCode({
   onQRCodeDecode: function( p_data ){
     $('#qrcode_result').html( p_data );
   }
  });